# Eliminar registros de una tabla si no existen en otra

Tags: sql-server

Amigos buenos días, tengo el siguiente problema.

En mi base de datos tengo dos tablas (EncabezadosFacturas y DetalleFacturas) ambas están unidas por un IDFactura.

De modo que para cada encabezado de factura, haya un detalle que contiene las transacciones facturadas. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Lo que necesito es validad que todos los registros en el DetalleFacturas tengan asociado un Encabezado, por lo que necesito hacer una comparación, ya que anteriormente alguien borró algunos encabezados y hay algunos detalles que ya no tienen un encabezado asociado.

Ojala me haya dado a entender

Comment: ¿Tus registros de detalle también tienen un ID propio?

Comment: si perfectamente.. y que probaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Es el mismo ID de los encabezados, tienen una llave constraint. Cuando se graba una factura se guardan encabezados y detalles en diferentes tablas pero con el mismo ID

Comment: Uhm, habría pensado que los detalles tendrían su propio identificador... si no, cómo los diferencias?? Pensando que una Factura puede tener varios detalles...

Comment: @quinqui tranquilamente la clave de la tabla detalle puede ser idfactura+idproducto, no es lo mejor pero es posible...

Comment: @quinqui la diferencia en el detalle es que IDfactura+IDTransaccion o IDproducto como dijo gbianchi anteriormente. De igual manera la respuesta de Lamak me ayudó mucho, esa fue la solución

Comment: Ah, ok. Yo te lo preguntaba insistentemente, porque la respuesta que yo te iba a dar requería una PK propia de Detalle (usando `LEFT JOIN`), pero qué bueno que la respuesta de Lamak te ayudó ^_^ (recuerda marcarla como la correcta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suena a un simple `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DetalleFacturas DF
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EncabezadosFacturas
                 WHERE IdFactura = DF.IdFactura)
;
```

Para borrar estas filas de la tabla, basta con:

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.DetalleFacturas DF
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EncabezadosFacturas
                 WHERE IdFactura = DF.IdFactura)
;
```

Comment: Como puedo agregar una cláusula para borrar el resultado de esta búsqueda?

Comment: Borrar de dónde?

Comment: Ejecuté el script que me diste y en efecto hay 3417 líneas de detalle que no tienen un encabezado asignado. Por lo que ya hice un backup de esta información y necesito ahora proceder a borrarla pero si cambio el delete por el select me da error

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Gracias, eso fué lo que intenté hacer pero me marca el siguiente error: Incorrect syntax near 'DF'.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, este fue el script final. 

DELETE T_FACTURACLI_FILAS
FROM dbo.T_FACTURACLI_FILAS DF
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.T_FACTURACLI
                 WHERE IdFactura = DF.IdFactura)
;

Comment: @GioGómez la sintaxis que está en mi respuesta debería funcionar tal como está escrito

Comment: @GioGómez en caso de postgresql es necesario agregar antes "as"...
SELECT *
FROM public.DetalleFacturas as df .....

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puede salir con un join, te comparto esto es de mucha ayuda.

[image: Joins en sql server]

Comment: Excelente imágenes para entender los Joins de SQL